# How do I use utilities in Temple Run?

Tags: temple-run

I saved up my Temple Run coins and bought a utility (specfically, the one that looks sort of like wings, and says "When active, you resurrect immediately after death").

I have played a whole bunch of runs (and died multiple times) but never was able to actually use the utility I bought.

What do I have to do to make this utility active, so that I can actually use it (and ressurect)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resurrect utility is activated by double tapping (that is, tapping twice, not once with two fingers) anywhere on the screen at any time.

After it's been activated, it'll only last for 30 seconds, after which, if you haven't died, it will disappear and be wasted.